# How increase speed of a code with map() function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and my code works perfectly with apply function. However, it is too slow when there are many rows. Is there is a way to increase the speed of a code by using `map()` instead of `apply()`?

I tried to use map in the following way, however got an error

```
data['postcode'] = list(map( data['address'],data.get('postcode', 'no postcode')))

#or chanage the order
data['city'] = list(map(data.get('postcode', 'no postcode'), data['address']))
```

> Series' object is not callable

Code with apply function:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")

data = {'lat': [39.92123,  39.93883,  39.93883,  39.91034,  39.91248],
        'lon': [116.51172, 116.51135, 116.51135, 116.51627, 116.47186] }  


# Create DataFrame  
data = pd.DataFrame(data) 
data['lat_lon'] = data['lat'].astype(str) + ',' + data['lon'].astype(str)


data['location'] = data['lat_lon'].apply(lambda lat_lon:  geolocator.reverse(lat_lon, language='en'))
data['address'] = data['location'].apply(lambda loc: loc.raw['address'])

data['postcode'] = data['address'].apply(lambda addr: addr.get('postcode', 'no postcode'))
data['city'] = data['address'].apply(lambda addr: addr.get('city', 'no city'))
data
```

Comment: I think your bottleneck is likely rate-limiting with openstreetmap's api, not processing power, right?  https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.options.default_timeout `Map()` won't help you there.

Comment: yes, the processing power is ok